# how to erase preview mode function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I got this project so I didn't make it from scratch. Here there is a function where the publication can be read in full if you are logged in but my client wants to delete this function so that everyone who has not logged in can read the publication in full. I have tried deleting the function but the result is still the same. if not logged in the publication cannot be read in full. is there a way or does anyone know which part should be replaced so that it can be according to my client's wishes?

I try remove the isPreviewMode still not working

here's the code

```
const PublicationDetail = () => {


 const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const queryKey = location.pathname.split('/');

  const [categoryList, setCategoryList] = useState([]);
  const [quickLinkList, setQuickLinkList] = useState<QuickLinkProps[]>([]);
  const [publicationData, setPublicationData] = useState<InfoDetailProps>();

  const [isPreviewMode, setIsPreviewMode] = useState(false);

  const toast = useToast();

  const { loginInfo } = useGlobalState();

  const getPublicationDetail = async () => {
    let param = '/' + queryKey[3];

    try {
      await fetchRequest({ method: 'GET', path: 'info' + param }).then(
        (response) => {
          setCategoryList(response.categories || []);
          setQuickLinkList(response.quickLinks || []);
          const responseData = response.data || {};
          setPublicationData(responseData);
          setIsPreviewMode(response.isPreviewMode || false);
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getPublicationDetail();
  }, []);

  const handleSelectedCategoryClick = () => {};

  const handleButtonClick = async () => {
    let param = '/' + queryKey[3];
    try {
      await fetchRequest({ method: 'GET', path: 'info/download' + param }).then(
        (response) => {
          if (response.linkUrl) {
            window.open(response.linkUrl);
          } else {
            toast({
              title: 'Error',
              description: response.message,
              status: 'error',
              duration: 9000,
              isClosable: true,
            });
          }
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      toast({
        title: 'Error',
        description: error.message,
        status: 'error',
        duration: 9000,
        isClosable: true,
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <Box h="30px" paddingLeft={{ base: '10px', lg: '3%' }} w="100%">
        <CustomBreadcrumb
          breadcrumbs={[
            ...BREADCRUMB_PUBLIKASI,
            { name: publicationData?.title || '', url: '' },
          ]}
        />
      </Box>
      <Stack
        w={{ xl: '100%' }}
        direction={['column', 'row']}
        spacing={{ md: '50px', base: '30px' }}
        paddingLeft={{ base: '3%' }}
        paddingRight={{ base: '3%' }}
        paddingTop={{ base: '0px', lg: '20px' }}
      >
        <Box
          w={{ md: '20%' }}
          h="400px"
          display={{ md: 'inline', base: 'none' }}
        >
          <Category headers={[]} />
          <VStack align="start" paddingTop="8px">
            {categoryList.map((c, i) => (
              <Text
                fontSize="md"
                color={BLACK}
                key={i}
                cursor="pointer"
                onClick={() => handleSelectedCategoryClick()}
              >
                {c}
              </Text>
            ))}
          </VStack>
        </Box>
        <Box w={{ md: '60%' }}>
          <Image
            w="100%"
            h="50vh"
            objectFit="cover"
            src={publicationData?.headerUrl || ''}
          ></Image>
          <Text
            className={'fontBold'}
            fontSize={{ md: '40px', base: '24px' }}
            color={BLACK}
            textAlign={{ base: 'center', lg: 'start' }}
            marginBottom="10"
            marginTop="4"
          >
            {publicationData?.title || ''}
          </Text>
          <Box textAlign="justify" fontSize={{ lg: 'md', base: 'sm' }} w="100%">
            {parse(publicationData?.content || '', options)}
            {isPreviewMode && (
              <>
                <Box
                  w={{ md: 'calc(60% - 100px)', base: '100%' }}
                  position="absolute"
                  marginTop="-150px"
                  display="block"
                  height="150px"
                  backgroundImage="linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 100%)"
                />
                <Center>
                  <CustomButton
                    text="BACA SELENGKAPNYA"
                    variant="transparent"
                    icon="none"
                    w=""
                    onClick={() => navigate(AUTH + LOGIN)}
                  />
                </Center>
              </>
            )}
          </Box>
          <Divider paddingTop="20px" />
        </Box>
        <Box w={{ md: '20%' }} fontSize={{ lg: 'md', base: 'sm' }}>
          <VStack align="start">
            <HStack>
              <Image src={ICONS.author} />
              <Text color={GREY}>{publicationData?.author}</Text>
            </HStack>
            <HStack>
              <Image src={ICONS.date} />
              <Text color={GREY}>
                {dayjs(publicationData?.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}
              </Text>
            </HStack>
            <HStack>
              <Image src={ICONS.category} />
              <Text color={GREY}>
                {publicationData?.categories?.join(', ')}
              </Text>
            </HStack>
            {publicationData?.subCategories &&
              publicationData?.subCategories?.length > 0 &&
              publicationData?.subCategories[0] !== '' && (
                <HStack>
                  <Image src={ICONS.subCategory} />
                  <Text color={GREY}>
                    {publicationData?.subCategories?.join(', ')}
                  </Text>
                </HStack>
              )}
            <HStack>
              <Image src={ICONS.view} />
              <Text color={GREY}>{publicationData?.views} pembaca</Text>
            </HStack>
            <HStack>
              <Image src={ICONS.download} />
              <Text color={GREY}>{publicationData?.downloads} unduhan</Text>
            </HStack>
            {loginInfo.isLogin && (
              <CustomButton
                w="100%"
                text="UNDUH"
                icon="download"
                variant="white"
                onClick={handleButtonClick}
              />
            )}
          </VStack>
        </Box>
      </Stack>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Comment: You could start by setting preview mode to true: `const [isPreviewMode, setIsPreviewMode] = useState(true);` and remove any line that could set it to false (this line: `setIsPreviewMode(... || false)`.

Comment: @Kokodoko done that already but still the same

Answer (score 0):

Alright, try `deleting` the following code-

```
{isPreviewMode && (
              <>
                <Box
                  w={{ md: 'calc(60% - 100px)', base: '100%' }}
                  position="absolute"
                  marginTop="-150px"
                  display="block"
                  height="150px"
                  backgroundImage="linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 100%)"
                />
                <Center>
                  <CustomButton
                    text="BACA SELENGKAPNYA"
                    variant="transparent"
                    icon="none"
                    w=""
                    onClick={() => navigate(AUTH + LOGIN)}
                  />
                </Center>
              </>
            )}
```

Comment: already try that too the text still not full